# How do I define the property of a function being its own inverse in Idris?

Tags: idris

I want to be able to say, for a function of f with signature t->t, that for all x in t, f(f(x)) = x.

When I run this:

```
%default total

-- The type of parity values - either Even or Odd
data Parity = Even | Odd

-- Even is the opposite of Odd and Odd is the opposite of Even
opposite: Parity -> Parity
opposite Even = Odd
opposite Odd  = Even

-- The 'opposite' function is it's own inverse
opposite_its_own_inverse : (p : Parity) -> opposite (opposite p) = p
opposite_its_own_inverse Even = Refl
opposite_its_own_inverse Odd  = Refl

-- abstraction of being one's own inverse

IsItsOwnInverse : {t : Type} -> (f: t->t) -> Type
IsItsOwnInverse {t} f = (x: t) -> f (f x) = x

opposite_IsItsOwnInverse : IsItsOwnInverse {t=Parity} opposite
opposite_IsItsOwnInverse = opposite_its_own_inverse
```

I get this error message:

```
- + Errors (1)
 `-- own_inverse_example.idr line 22 col 25:
     When checking right hand side of opposite_IsItsOwnInverse with expected type
             IsItsOwnInverse opposite

     Type mismatch between
             (p : Parity) ->
             opposite (opposite p) = p (Type of opposite_its_own_inverse)
     and
             (x : Parity) -> opposite (opposite x) = x (Expected type)

     Specifically:
             Type mismatch between
                     opposite (opposite v0)
             and
                     opposite (opposite v0)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is that just a bug?

If I replace the last 'opposite_its_own_inverse' with '?hole', I get:

```
Holes

This buffer displays the unsolved holes from the currently-loaded code. Press
the [P] buttons to solve the holes interactively in the prover.

- + Main.hole [P]
 `--   opposite : Parity -> Parity
     -------------------------------------------------------
      Main.hole : (x : Parity) -> opposite (opposite x) = x
```

Answer (score 4):

The name for this property is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)). Your type for this property is pretty good but I like writing it like so:

```
Involution : (t -> t) -> t -> Type
Involution f x = f (f x) = x
```

The first problem with your `opposite_IsItsOwnInverse` is that you haven't fully applied `Involution` so you haven't yet gotten a type. You also need apply a `Parity` so that `Involution` gives a `Type`, like so:

```
opposite_IsItsOwnInverse : Involution opposite p
```

That `p` is an implicit argument. Implicit arguments are implicitly created by lowercase identifiers in type signatures. This is like writing:

```
opposite_IsItsOwnInverse : {p : Parity} -> Involution opposite p
```

But this leads to another problem with the signature - `opposite` is also lowercase, so it's getting treated as an implicit argument! (This is why you get the confusing error message, Idris has created *another* variable called `opposite`) You have 2 possible solutions here: qualify the identifier, or use an identifier which starts with an uppercase letter.

I'll assume the module you're writing uses the default name of `Main`. The final type signature looks like:

```
opposite_IsItsOwnInverse : Involution Main.opposite p
```

And the implementation will just use the implicit argument and supply it to the function you've already written:

```
opposite_IsItsOwnInverse {p} = opposite_its_own_inverse p
```

Comment: Yes, it was a case of the lower-case implicit parameter feature, a gotcha for newbies like myself. The absolute minimum change required is for me to prefix the last `opposite` with `Main.` (it compiles happily if I leave my original implicit `t` parameter as it is). I think it is a bug that the error message was telling me about two different things with the name "opposite" without telling me that they were different (thus perpetuating my original confusion). I note some similar implicit-parameter-confusion issues already raised on the Github project, but maybe not this exact same issue.